# What ports does Apache Hadoop version 1.0.3 use for intracluster communicaion of the daemons

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, rhel, elastic-map-reduce

I know port 22 is only used for control scripts.

But i need to know what ports I should open for my 3 node cluster. 2 slaves, 1 namenode/jobtracker.

On what port do the daemons run? On what ports are the URLs displayed?

The hadoop distro is: Apache Hadoop version 1.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By URL I assume you mean the JobTracker and TaskTracker interfaces. The breakdown is as follows:

```
Namenode                50070   
Datanodes               50075 
Secondarynamenode       50090 
JobTracker              50030   
TaskTracker             50060
```

Comment: I only have 2 ports available due to restrictions by our firewall team. 7000 and 7199. How can I view all the URLS for hadoop administration by just these 2 ports?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/) are the default port number in Hadoop.

Comment: I only have 2 ports available due to restrictions by our firewall team. 7000 and 7199. How can I view all the URLS for hadoop administration by just these 2 ports?